# Multiple conditions on pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, multiple-columns, multiple-conditions, logical-and

I have a list of conditions to be run on the dataset to sort huge data.

`df = A Huge_dataframe.`
eg.

```
  Index D1  D2  D3   D5      D6
    0   8   5   0  False   True
    1  45  35   0   True  False
    2  35  10   1  False   True
    3  40   5   2   True  False
    4  12  10   5  False  False
    5  18  15  13  False   True
    6  25  15   5   True  False
    7  35  10  11  False   True
    8  95  50   0  False  False
```

I have to sort above df based on given orders:

```
orders = [[A, B],[D, ~E, B], [~C, ~A], [~C, A]...] 
#(where A, B, C , D, E are the conditions)
```

eg.

```
A = df['D1'].le(50)
B = df['D2'].ge(5)
C = df['D3'].ne(0)
D = df['D1'].ne(False)
E = df['D1'].ne(True)
# In the real scenario, I have 64 such conditions to be run on 5 million records.
```

eg.
I have to run all these conditions to get the resultant output.

What is the easiest way to achieve the following task,  to order them using `for loop` or `map` or `.apply`?

```
  df = df.loc[A & B]
  df = df.loc[D & ~E & B]
  df = df.loc[~C & ~A]
  df = df.loc[~C & A]
```

Resultant df would be my expected output.

Here I am more interested in knowing, how would you use loop or map or .apply, If I want to run `multiple conditions` which are stored in a list. Not the resultant output.

such as:

```
for i in orders:
   df = df[all(i)] # I am not able to implement this logic for each order
```

Comment: @ScottBoston - Just the resultant output when merged those conditions on a datagrams. Here I am more interested in knowing `df.loc` on `multiple conditions` which are stored in a list.

Comment: @ScottBoston - I have updated the question, please check again. A is not numeric. Basically A is a series which could be output of  `A = df['D1 '> 50]`

Comment: What Scott meant is it is better if you can edit the question body with the definitions for A,B,C,D etc..

Comment: @anky - Will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `bitwise and` all the elements inside `orders`. In which case:

```
df = df[np.concatenate(orders).all(0)]
```